# finding scores from csv file

Tags: python, csv

I am new to SO, I need a help in coding my python script for the following query.

i have a csv file with comments, and also i have another csv file with scores(contains score of every word). I need to find the score of all the words in that comment by parsing that score csv file and attain the **added scores result** output as follows

comments:

```
sno  username  comment
1    lil      i like @dff burger
2    cdd      i hate those hamburger
....
```

scores:

```
sno  word  score
1    like   2
2    hate  -2
3    burger 1
....
```

Desired output:

```
sno  comment                 addscore
1    i like @dff burger         3
2    i hate those hamburger    -2
...........
```

my code:-

```
import csv

with open('comment.csv', 'rb') as csvfile:
   reader = csv.reader(csvfile)


with open('score.csv', 'rb') as csvfile:
   reader1 = csv.reader(csvfile)
   for word in reader1:
       if word in reader:
           ## i stuck with logic here##
```

please help me with my code

Comment: How big is your scores csv file? You can create a dictionary of scores csv file where your key will be `word` and `score` will be value. Then split the comment using `split function in python`, and check if the word present in dictionary, if it is present then add the value. This is how you can approach this problem

Comment: the dictionary is very big

Comment: Check if you create dictionary of your score csv file otherwise the program will be very inefficient. Did you get the approach?

Comment: cud u help me with a skeletal program structure..?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will get you started, it's a bit of a hack, do what you want with the output, write it to csv or whatever. I use pandas here for convenience, you don't need to though.

```
import pandas as pd

df_comment = pd.read_csv('comment.csv')
df_score   = pd.read_csv('score.csv')

cnt = 0
for i in  df_comment['comment']:
        kp = []
        for  j in i.split(' '):
                if j in [k for k in df_score['word']]:
                        pos = [x for x, y in enumerate(df_score['word']) if y==j]
                        kp.append(df_score['score'][pos[0]])
        cnt= cnt+1

        print cnt, i, sum(kp)
```

Hope it helps.